# Py shell discover args using inspect (pyparsing)

Tags: pyparsing, inspect

Basic question from newbie in steep learning curve.

Can someone please explain how to discover the args/params to a Class using inspect within python shell

For example, within pyparsing, the Combine Class has the kwarg 'joinString'. How would I discover that (and any other it might have) using inspect within the python shell?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `help(Combine)`? If you must use inspect, then probably `inspect.getargspec(Combine.__init__)`.

Comment: Paul thank you. I didn't know about help(Combine). This might flatten my learning curve (-:

For delimitedList can the delimiter be set to something like endOfLine?

Really great to have learned about that help func. Thank you

Comment: Paul, I changed my strategy & got what I needed. I'm delighted with the outcome. Thank you for writing and making this package available.

Comment: That's great! There are also online docs at http://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/, and many examples on the pyparsing wiki at http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/